# How to serialize and unserialize an array with correct format

Tags: php, arrays

I have an like below:

```
$permis =array(
 'employee' => array(
      'myprofile' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
        ),
        'view emp' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0', 'notes' => '0', 'onboard' => '0', 'offboard' => '0', 'charts' => '0'
        )
    )
);
```

If i am serialize this means it will look like below:

```
a:1:{s:8:"employee";a:2:{s:9:"myprofile";a:9:{s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:8:"personal";s:1:"0";s:3:"job";s:1:"0";s:5:"leave";s:1:"0";s:10:"permission";s:1:"0";s:17:"bonus & commision";s:1:"0";s:8:"document";s:1:"0";s:17:"emergency contact";s:1:"0";s:8:"benifits";s:1:"0";}s:8:"view emp";a:13:{s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:8:"personal";s:1:"0";s:3:"job";s:1:"0";s:5:"leave";s:1:"0";s:10:"permission";s:1:"0";s:17:"bonus & commision";s:1:"0";s:8:"document";s:1:"0";s:17:"emergency contact";s:1:"0";s:8:"benifits";s:1:"0";s:5:"notes";s:1:"0";s:7:"onboard";s:1:"0";s:8:"offboard";s:1:"0";s:6:"charts";s:1:"0";}}}
```

an if i unserialize means it will look like below:

```
Array ( [employee] => Array ( [myprofile] => Array ( [default] => 0 [personal] => 0 [job] => 0 [leave] => 0 [permission] => 0 [bonus & commision] => 0 [document] => 0 [emergency contact] => 0 [benifits] => 0 ) [view emp] => Array ( [default] => 0 [personal] => 0 [job] => 0 [leave] => 0 [permission] => 0 [bonus & commision] => 0 [document] => 0 [emergency contact] => 0 [benifits] => 0 [notes] => 0 [onboard] => 0 [offboard] => 0 [charts] => 0 ) ) )
```

What i need is in my unserialize array will br like below:

```
array(
 'employee' => array(
      'myprofile' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
        ),
        'view emp' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0', 'notes' => '0', 'onboard' => '0', 'offboard' => '0', 'charts' => '0'
        )
    )
)
```

How to Do that in right way.

Please Help Me

Comment: What is wrong in your unserialized array?

Comment: Your Expected output and unserialized array are same. So, i don't get it that what is wrong with it.

Comment: use `echo '<pre>'; print_r()` it's only for checking.

Comment: actually this is the code i am using for both serialize and unserialize             $val1=serialize($permis);
   
   print_r($val1);
   
   $val2=unserialize($val1);
   print_r($val2);
   
   If i use the following echo means it will be error undefined index default:                             
  
                        echo $val2['default'];

Comment: Post the error you get when echo the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your correct array. If you want to print the array with structure use

```
<?php 
echo "<pre>",print_r($array),"</pre>";
?>
```

Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php as it will be explained. Here is an easy online generator where you can test if your array is valid for sirialize http://php.fnlist.com/php/serialize

**EDIT**

```
 <?php 

    $permis =array(
     'employee' => array(
          'myprofile' => array(
            'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
            ),
            'view emp' => array(
            'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0', 'notes' => '0', 'onboard' => '0', 'offboard' => '0', 'charts' => '0'
            )
        )
    );

    $serialized = serialize($permis);
    echo "<pre>",print_r($serialized),"</pre>"; //echo serialized array
```

will output

> a:1:{s:8:"employee";a:2:{s:9:"myprofile";a:9:{s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:8:"personal";s:1:"0";s:3:"job";s:1:"0";s:5:"leave";s:1:"0";s:10:"permission";s:1:"0";s:17:"bonus & commision";s:1:"0";s:8:"document";s:1:"0";s:17:"emergency contact";s:1:"0";s:8:"benifits";s:1:"0";}s:8:"view emp";a:13:{s:7:"default";s:1:"0";s:8:"personal";s:1:"0";s:3:"job";s:1:"0";s:5:"leave";s:1:"0";s:10:"permission";s:1:"0";s:17:"bonus & commision";s:1:"0";s:8:"document";s:1:"0";s:17:"emergency contact";s:1:"0";s:8:"benifits";s:1:"0";s:5:"notes";s:1:"0";s:7:"onboard";s:1:"0";s:8:"offboard";s:1:"0";s:6:"charts";s:1:"0";}}}

```
 $unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
    echo "<pre>",print_r($unserialized),"</pre>"; //echo unserialized array
    ?>
```

will output

> array(
>    'employee' => array(
>         'myprofile' => array(
>           'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
>           ),
>           'view emp' => array(
>           'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0', 'notes' => '0', 'onboard' => '0', 'offboard' => '0', 'charts' => '0'
>           )
>       )
>   );

I checked this twice. The array is correct and the unserialize is also correct.
http://php.fnlist.com/php/serialize
If you want to echo a key of the array use a foreach or something like this

```
<?php
echo $unserilized['employee']['myprofile']['personal'];
```

?>
will output

> 0 as it is the value of the key

Comment: Here $val1 is to store my serialized array and $val2 is used to store unserialized array,   if i use print_r($val2) means it's working fine. but if i use echo means it will be error. For Example echo $val2['default'] means it will be undefined index error. how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The array is unserialized correctly, your problem is that you are trying to access the elements in an incorrect way.

When you write `$val2['default']`, it looks for the 'default' key in the top level, where you only have 'employee'.

In order to access the 'default' for either employee, you'll need to index it level by level, like this:

```
$val2['employee']['myprofile']['default']
```